# Dropdown list resets after selection is made in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have a dropdown list in my view where the user can select a staff member and then filter by the selected staff then they will be shown the records for that selected staff member only. I noticed that upon hitting the search button, the records for the selected staff member shows but the dropdown resets to the first staff member. Is there any way to show the selected staff member even after the page refreshes?

My View:

```
<form action="{{route('exportVehiclesToExcel')}}" method="GET" >
                  <div style="display: flex">
                    <div>
                      <label>Pick a staff member</label>
                      <select name="smsstaff_key" id="smsstaff_key" required>
                            @foreach ($staff as $staffMember) 
                        <option  value="{{$staffMember->smsstaff_key}}" {{request()->input('smsstaff_key') === $staffMember->smsstaff_key ? 'selected="selected"' : ''}}>{{$staffMember->name}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                      </select>
                        <div style="margin-left: 3px;">
                          <button class="btn btn-primary" formaction="searching">Filter by selected staff member</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin-left: 50px;">
                      <label>From:</label>
                      <input style="width: 14em"  type="date" class="form-control" name="startDate" value="{{ $startDate }}" required>
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin-left: 20px;">
                        <label>To:</label>
                        <input style="width: 14em" type="date" class="form-control" name="endDate" value="{{ $endDate }}" required>
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin-left: 20px;">
                      <button class="btn btn-success" formaction="tech/export/" type="submit">Export filtered</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div  style="margin-left: 10px;"> 
                  <a href="{{"/techAll/export/"}}" target="_blank" class="btn ">All to Excel</a>
                </div>
```

I also tried to put this code in my view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('smsstaff_key').value = "<?php echo $_GET['smsstaff_key'];?>";
</script>
```

however, it returns an `undefined array key "smsstaff_key"` error.

Comment: Try to remove the triple "equal" symbol and use two. And use just "selected" instead of "selected=selected"

Comment: @GiacomoM So make it `<select name="smsstaff_key" id="smsstaff_key" required>
                          @foreach ($staff as $staffMember) 
                      <option  value="{{$staffMember->smsstaff_key}}"  {{request()->input('smsstaff_key') == $staffMember->smsstaff_key ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{$staffMember->name}}</option>
                          @endforeach
                    </select>` ?

Answer (score -1):

This is what Laravel uses to handle sent values after the request:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#old-input

Comment: Please explain in more detail than providing a link